# Read textfile with repeating entries into list (similar to properties)

Tags: java, file, properties, io

Is there a proper way to read a textfile like this

```
picture = germany
correctAnswer = GERMANY
otherLetters = KLBCDOP

picture = italy
correctAnswer = ITALY
otherLetters = OUILMNKDS

picture = egypt
correctAnswer = EGYPT
otherLetters = YWMPSADCH

picture = usa
correctAnswer = USA
otherLetters = KLPOMNAGSYW
```

and store the data in - for example - a list? So i could access the data by calling

```
String picture = list.get(0).get("picture");
String otherLetters = list.get(0).get("otherLetters");
...
```

Sure, i could do it manually, but is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you creating a class with `picture`, `correctAnswer` and `otherLetters` properties?

Comment: I have to create several files like this to store language dependent data.

Comment: So I'd suggest creating several types :) It'll make any code using it much simpler in the long run, I suspect. What have you tried so far with your current approach? It sounds like you're after a `List<Map<String, String>>` where you create a new map every time you read a blank line. You should consider what escape sequences you need (if any) - and if you can possibly avoid getting the data in this nasty format to start with, that would be good too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as concern with your question, You can create arraylist of hashmap like below.. replace D:\file_to_read.txt with your file path..

```
    try {
        File file = new File("D:\\file_to_read.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String arry[] = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            if ("".equals(line)) {
                list.add(map);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                System.out.println("blank");
            } else {
                arry = line.split("=");
                map.put(arry[0].trim(), arry[1].trim());
            }

        }

        String picture = list.get(0).get("picture");
        String otherLetters = list.get(0).get("otherLetters");


        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Just as information: using this solution the textfile has to end with a blank line. Otherwise the last element will be skipped.